# Django Rest Framework SerializerMethodField Pass Extra Argument

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model method that requires the request user to be pass in as an extra argument:

**Model Method:**

```
def has_achieved(self, user):
    return AwardLog.objects.filter(user=user, badge=self).count() > 0
```

Using the Django Rest Framework I want to call this put don't know how to pass in the  extra argument from the Serializer:

```
class BadgeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    achieved = serializers.SerializerMethodField(source='has_achieved(request.user???)')

    class Meta:
       model = Badge
       fields = ("name", "achieved")
```

I cannot find anywhere this scenario has been documented. is there a method in my views I could override to pass this in and use? Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just to follow-up I did this by using `self.context['request'].user` ie.

```
def has_achieved(self, obj):

    return obj.has_achieved(self.context['request'].user)
```

Comment: That's the way to go :)